# perl script that does a pg_dumpall of postgres

Tags: windows, postgresql, perl, database-backups, pg-dump

Not sure if this script is original or from an internet source but I inherited this for a Windows system that's running PostgreSQL.

However this script only backs up individual tables. I would like to modify it so that it does a pg_dumpall of the Postgres so that everything is included (such as user accounts, etc).

Is this possible to do with the existing script?

```
#
use DBI;
use Time::Piece;

$t = localtime;
chomp($todays_date = $t->mday);
@tables = ('orders', 'customer', 'rates');
$dir = "Z:\\PostgreSQL\\Backups";
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=commerce", "someadmin", "password1") || die "$DBI::errstr";

foreach $table(@tables)
{
    $file = "$dir\\$table.dump_$todays_date";
#    $type = ( -d $file) ? "dir" : "file";
    if( -e $file)
    {
        print "Deleting $file\n";
        unlink($file);
    }
    print "Dumping $table\n";
    $file =~ s/\\/\//g;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("COPY $table to '$file'");
    $sth->execute();
}
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking and the feedback here I decided to just start new with a batch script using the pg_dump command since this would allow a binary dump format and restoration with pg_restore.

To not overfill my drive and to keep a max of 31 days of backups I have the script name each backup with the day of the month only (i.e. "10.dump", "21.dump", "31.dump", etc).

Subsequent backups of the same name would simply be overwritten.

Windows Task Scheduler would take care of launching the script:

```
@echo OFF
REM Script that does a pg_dump binary backup of the commerce database

REM passes the password to the pg_dump command
SET PGPASSWORD=password1

REM switch to Z drive
Z:

REM switch to bin directory where pg_dump lives
cd Z:\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin

REM pg_dump command which names dump backup of commerce db as the day of the month 1-31. This way we only keep 31 days of backup and do not overfill Z drive

pg_dump.exe -U someadmin -F c -d commerce > "Z:\PostgreSQL\Backups_pg_dump\%DATE:~-7,2%.dump"
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do this using a select statement to the tables:

```
$tableh = $dbh->prepare("SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables");
$tables = $tableh->fetchall_arrayref();
$tableh->finish();
```

This will give you a list of tables from postgres, which you can thin modify your foreach loop as follows:

```
foreach $table_ref (@$tables) {
    my $table = $table_ref->[0];
```

And continue on from there.

Note that this probably isn't the correct way to back up a database and you probably should use `pg_dumpall` instead.  But I don't know what your requirements are so...  here ya go!

Comment: What about schemas?